# How can I get a picture of the category in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

[image]

I can get all the category names and ids by the following code, but I can only get the thumbnails of the first level classification, can't get the pictures of the subclasses? What should I do? If you can help me, this will be a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to load the category model each time.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$imageUrl = $category->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image of a category after load category. Following code will help you.

```
protected $_storeManager;
public function __construct(

\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

}
```

public function getThumbnailUrl($imageName){
     $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
          \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
     ) . 'catalog/category/' . $imageName;
     return $url;
}

$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$load_cat = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($_subcategory->getId());

$this->_customcatimage->getThumbnailUrl($main_cat->getthumbnail());